# Laravel Event exceeds pusher limit

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

When firing an event pusher complains that it's exceeding the size limit. While google I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51147924/laravel-event-exceeds-pusher-allowed-limit) post.

I tried to reduce my payload by only transmitting the ID, but it is still complaining. Am I missing something? I don't think there's a way to reduce my payload any more.

```php
event(new MessageApproved(['id' => $message->id]));
```

The event is pretty straightforward as well:

```php
class MessageApproved implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
    * Create a new event instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
    * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
    *
    * @return Channel|array
    */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('messages');
    }

    /**
    * The event's broadcast name.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'approved';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this, maybe there's something wrong on your Pusher settings?

Comment: Have you checked what’s being sent to Pusher as an HTTP request?